How to Merge Cells with the Same Value in AG Grid Using Row Span or any other method in React?
I'm working on a React project where I use AG Grid to display some data. I have a column called "Year Range" which is dynamically calculated from a date field called stoppageStart. I want to merge cells in this column that have the same "Year Range" value.
Here's a simplified version of my data and column definitions:
const rowData = [
  { stoppageStart: '2013-01-01', name: 'John' },
  { stoppageStart: '2013-06-01', name: 'Doe' },
  { stoppageStart: '2014-01-01', name: 'Smith' },
  { stoppageStart: '2014-06-01', name: 'Brown' },
  { stoppageStart: '2015-01-01', name: 'Taylor' },
];

const columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Year Range',
    field: 'yearRange',
    valueGetter: (params) => {
      const stoppageStart = params.data.stoppageStart;
      const year = new Date(stoppageStart).getFullYear();
      const nextYear = year + 1;
      return `${year}-${nextYear}`;
    },
    cellRenderer: 'customCellRenderer',
    rowSpan: (params) => {
      const yearRange = params.data.yearRange;
      let span = 1;
      for (let i = params.node.rowIndex + 1; i < params.api.getDisplayedRowCount(); i++) {
        const nextRow = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(i);
        if (nextRow.data.yearRange === yearRange) {
          span++;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
      return span;
    },
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Name',
    field: 'name',
  },
];

I use a custom cell renderer to handle the merged cells:
const CustomCellRenderer = (params) => {
  if (params.node.rowSpan && params.node.rowSpan > 1) {
    return (
      <div style={{
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '100%',
        gridRowEnd: `span ${params.node.rowSpan}`
      }}>
        {params.value}
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <span>{params.value}</span>;
};


My AG Grid component is set up like this:
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

const MyGridComponent = () => {
  const [rowData] = useState([
    { stoppageStart: '2013-01-01', name: 'John' },
    { stoppageStart: '2013-06-01', name: 'Doe' },
    { stoppageStart: '2014-01-01', name: 'Smith' },
    { stoppageStart: '2014-06-01', name: 'Brown' },
    { stoppageStart: '2015-01-01', name: 'Taylor' },
  ]);

  const columnDefs = useMemo(() => [
    {
      headerName: 'Year Range',
      field: 'yearRange',
      flex: 1,
      cellStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      valueGetter: (params) => {
        const stoppageStart = params.data.stoppageStart;
        const year = new Date(stoppageStart).getFullYear();
        const nextYear = year + 1;
        return `${year}-${nextYear}`;
      },
      cellRenderer: 'customCellRenderer',
      rowSpan: (params) => {
        const yearRange = params.data.yearRange;
        let span = 1;
        for (let i = params.node.rowIndex + 1; i < params.api.getDisplayedRowCount(); i++) {
          const nextRow = params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(i);
          if (nextRow.data.yearRange === yearRange) {
            span++;
          } else {
            break;
          }
        }
        return span;
      },
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
    },
  ], []);

  const gridOptions = {
    frameworkComponents: {
      customCellRenderer: CustomCellRenderer,
    },
    rowData,
    columnDefs,
  };

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact {...gridOptions} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyGridComponent;


Problem:
The row spanning doesn't seem to work as expected, and the cells are not merging correctly. I want cells with the same "Year Range" value to be merged, showing the value only once in the merged cell. The values will be like '2013-2014','2014-2015',etc.
Question:
How can I correctly merge cells with the same "Year Range" value in AG Grid using row spanning in a React application? Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated!
